# Store RMS to memory card

Tags: java-me, midp, rms

I had question, is it possible to store RMS to Memory card? Since we use large amount data to store in RMS. Is there any alternative way?

I want to know how RMS memory is calculated?

Comment: does your device support [FileConnection (JSR 75)](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/) API?

Comment: Thanks gnat, FileConnection works. But i want to know how RMS memory is calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how RMS memory is calculated

API for above is [RecordStore#getSizeAvailable()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/rms/RecordStore.html#getSizeAvailable%28%29), see method javadocs:

> ...Returns the amount of additional room (in bytes) available for this record store to grow. Note that this is not necessarily the amount of extra MIDlet-level data which can be stored, as implementations may store additional data structures with each record to support integration with native applications, synchronization, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get Total memory size

**Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()**

To get free memory size

**Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()**